# Custom typeclass instantiation: couldn't match expected type ‘b’ with actual type ‘Int’

Tags: haskell

I am currently trying to implement a typeclass that allows me to convert any of custom types to an `Integral` (those types should all be convertible to an index or a weight). In this specific case I want to use it to make sure that a musical note, on a given octave, can be converted to the index of a piano keyboard key:

```
import Data.Int

class Convertible a where
  toIntegral :: Integral b => a -> b

data Note = Note Tone Int

instance Convertible Note where
    toIntegral (Note t o) = o * 12 + toIntegral t
```

However the compiler complains my implementation of `toIntegral` for `Note` does not comply with my `Convertible` typeclass.

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘b’ with actual type ‘Int’
  ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      num :: forall b. Integral b => Note -> b
    at src/Note.hs:11:5
• In the expression: octave * 12 + (num tone)
  In an equation for ‘num’:
      num (Note tone octave) = octave * 12 + (num tone)
  In the instance declaration for ‘Convertible Note’
• Relevant bindings include
    num :: Note -> b (bound at src/Note.hs:11:5)
```

As far as I understand, it considers the content of my `toIntegral` function evaluates to an `a -> Int`, when I constrained it to be an `Integral => b -> a -> b`. Now I don't understand what's wrong, because `Int` implements the `Integral` typeclass, right?

Can you help me understand what I'm obviously doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type variables are chosen by the caller, not by the callee. In your case, `toIntegral` can not choose `b`, its caller does. According to its type, all of these uses must type check

```
toIntegral (Note t o) :: Int
toIntegral (Note t o) :: Integer
toIntegral (Note t o) :: Word32
-- etc.
```

The solution is to convert `Int`s as well, i.e. convert `o`, so to return any integral `b`, and not just an `Int`.

For instance, `fromIntegral o` can convert `o` to any `Num` type, hence any `Integral` one.

Anyway, are you sure you really need that type for your `toIntegral`?

Comment: Surely, you mean `fromIntegral` from the `Integral` class. :D

Comment: @gallais I think it should be fixed now. As usual, numeric conversions are a bit tricky in Haskell. The only way I can see to perform the conversion is to go through `Integer`, which feels a bit clunky. I wonder if `toEnum` is guaranteed to be equivalent to that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `toIntegral (Note t o) = fromIntegral o * 12 + toIntegral t` will work just fine.

Comment: I see my mistake now. What you're saying is that when I define the function, and say "you're returning a `b` that's an integral" although the actual implementation of my function is returning an Int, the compiler can't be sure until it's actually called, hence can't check the compliance to `Integral` is that right?

Anyways, the `fromIntegral` trick made it, thanks a lot folks!

Comment: Also, you folks are right, it might be good enough for me to enforce an `Int` return type from my `toIntegral` instead of the wider `Integral` typeclass...

Comment: @Oleiade No. The point is that you can't choose `b = Int`. The type you use is too general, it promises too much to the caller. Consider `f :: Num a => a->a ; f x = (3::Int)`, this wouldn't type check for the same reason.